# How to change the next/IMage SRC conditionally on various screensize in taiwind css?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I am using the `next/Image` component to set an image and add styling using `tailwindcss`, I got stuck at this point.

#### What I want?

I wanted to change the `src` of the image to be changed on the basics of screensize. Like if I am in `sm` screen size, then it should display `IMG1` and after `md` screen size, it should display `IMG2`.

Also, I want to change the `height` and 'width`attributes of the`next/Image` component subjective to the different screensize.

How Can I do so?

#### Code

```
import React from "react";
import imgurl from "../public/dog.jpg";
import imgurl2 from "../public/Ash.jpg";
import Image from "next/image";

const Projects = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="min-h-full container">
        
        
                    <Image
                      height={400}
                      width={800}
                      className="object-contain rounded-t-lg md:h-auto md:w-48 md:rounded-none md:rounded-l-lg "
                      src={imgurl2}
                      alt=""
                    />
           
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Projects;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had solved the issue by this,

Putting the two images in a `div wrapper` and hiding them on the basis of screen size.

```
     <div className="block sm:hidden">
                    <Image
                      height={350}
                      width={700}
                      className="object-cover rounded-t-lg "
                      src={imgurl2}
                      alt=""
                    />
      </div>
      <div className="hidden sm:block">
                    <Image
                      width="500%"
                      height="1000%"
                      className="object-cover rounded-t-lg md:h-auto md:w-48 md:rounded-none md:rounded-l-lg"
                      src={imgurl3}
                      alt=""
                    />
      </div>
```